find the missing sequence in Oracle DB
I have a table date, store code, do_no. some stores have missing sequence number. Data looks like Source. I'm not able to find missing doc_no in all stores. Each store doc_no start digit is different. STO1 starts wth 1, ST02 start with 2,ST03 3 etc..
I'm expecting results to find which store have missing doc_no. example expected results. Expected Results

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

One option is to create list of all doc_no values (span from min to max value per store_code) and then use the minus set operator to extract missing values.
Sample data:
SQL> with test (store_code, doc_no) as
  2    (select 'ST03', 32000077 from dual union all
  3     select 'ST03', 32000079 from dual union all
  4     select 'ST03', 32000080 from dual union all
  5     --
  6     select 'ST02', 22000130 from dual union all
  7     select 'ST02', 22000131 from dual union all
  8     select 'ST02', 22000133 from dual
  9    ),

Query begins here:
 10  temp as
 11    (select store_code, min(doc_no) min_no, max(doc_no) max_no
 12     from test
 13     group by store_code
 14    ),
 15  all_docs as
 16    (select store_code,
 17            min_no + column_value - 1 as doc_no
 18     from temp cross join
 19       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 20                           connect by level <= max_no - min_no + 1
 21                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 22    )
 23  select store_code, doc_no from all_docs
 24  minus
 25  select store_code, doc_no from test;

STORE_CODE       DOC_NO
------------ ----------
ST02           22000132
ST03           32000078

SQL>


You can also use MATCH_RECOGNIZE:
SELECT store_code, gapfrom_docno + level AS doc_no FROM (
    SELECT * FROM test
    MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
        PARTITION BY store_code
        ORDER BY doc_no
        MEASURES MAX(doc_no) AS gapfrom_docno, NEXT(doc_no) AS gapto_docno
        PATTERN( hole )
        DEFINE 
            hole AS MAX(doc_no) < NEXT(doc_no) - 1
    )
)
CONNECT BY PRIOR store_code = store_code AND gapfrom_docno + level < gapto_docno
    AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL
;

Or
WITH test (store_code, doc_no) AS (
    SELECT 'ST03', 32000077 from dual union all
    SELECT 'ST03', 32000080 from dual union all
--
    SELECT 'ST02', 22000130 from dual union all
    SELECT 'ST02', 22000131 from dual union all
    SELECT 'ST02', 22000133 from dual
)
    SELECT * FROM test
    MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
        PARTITION BY store_code
        ORDER BY doc_no
        MEASURES MAX(doc_no) + 1 AS gapfrom_docno, NEXT(doc_no) - 1 AS gapto_docno
        PATTERN( hole )
        DEFINE 
            hole AS MAX(doc_no) < NEXT(doc_no) - 1
    )
;

to get the result as table of (from, to) pairs:
SELECT * FROM test
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
    PARTITION BY store_code
    ORDER BY doc_no
    MEASURES MAX(doc_no) + 1 AS gapfrom_docno, NEXT(doc_no) - 1 AS gapto_docno
    PATTERN( hole )
    DEFINE 
        hole AS MAX(doc_no) < NEXT(doc_no) - 1
)


To do it with only a single table scan (and without needing to generate the entire range of values), you can use the LAG analytic function to find the previous value and then use a LATERAL join to a hierarchical function to generate the missing values:
SELECT store_code,
       missing_doc_no
FROM   (
         SELECT store_code,
                doc_no,
                LAG(doc_no) OVER (PARTITION BY store_code ORDER BY doc_no)
                  AS prev_doc_no
         FROM   table_name
       )
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT prev_doc_no + LEVEL AS missing_doc_no
         FROM   DUAL
         START WITH prev_doc_no + 1 < doc_no
         CONNECT BY LEVEL < doc_no - prev_doc_no
       )

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (posted_date, store_code, doc_no) AS
  SELECT DATE '2024-05-11', 'ST03', 32000077 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2024-05-14', 'ST03', 32000079 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2024-05-14', 'ST03', 32000080 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2024-05-11', 'ST02', 22000130 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2024-05-11', 'ST02', 22000131 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2024-05-12', 'ST02', 22000133 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2024-05-10', 'ST01', 12000193 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2024-05-11', 'ST01', 12000194 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2024-05-13', 'ST01', 12000196 FROM DUAL;

Outputs;



STORE_CODE
MISSING_DOC_NO




ST01
12000195


ST02
22000132


ST03
32000078



fiddle
